# Does $x \notin A \backslash B $ mean $x \notin A \wedge x \in B$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

Does $x \notin A \backslash B $ mean $x \notin A \wedge x \in B$? I am trying to prove a statement where I need to use $x \notin  A \backslash B$. But it does not help me, so I am assuming I am using the wrong tautology. The statement I am trying to prove is the following:

$$x \in A \wedge x\notin A\backslash B \Rightarrow x\in A \cap B$$

Comment: It means $x\in A\wedge x\notin B$.

Comment: I think that is what $x \in A \backslash B$ means.

Comment: Sorry; misread what you wrote. Since $x\in A\setminus B$ means $x\in A\wedge x\notin B$, then $x\notin A\setminus B$ means $\neg(x\in A\wedge x\notin B)$. The negation of $P\wedge Q$ is $(\neg P)\vee(\neg Q)$, so here you get that $x\notin A\setminus B$ must be a disjunction (not a conjunctions). It means $(x\notin A)\vee (x\in B)$.

Comment: $A \setminus B = A \cap B^c$. So $x \notin A \setminus B$ means $\lnot(x \in A \land x \notin B)$ which is equivalent to $x \notin A \lor x \in B$. Perhaps some reviewing of De Morgan's laws is in order.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it means $x\not\in A$ **or** $x\in B$ (or put perhaps more intuitively, "if $x\in A$ then $x\in B$"). That is, your "$\wedge$" should be a "$\vee$."

Remember that $A\setminus B$ is the set of all things in $A$ which aren't in $B$. So if $x$ *isn't* in $A\setminus B$, this means one of those two conditions must fail: either $x$ wasn't in $A$ to begin with, or $x$ was one of the $B$-things that got removed.

Comment: That makes sense. Therefore, going back to the statement I am trying to prove, we can write $x \in A \wedge (x \notin A \vee x \in B)$. We know $x \notin A$ cannot happen, since we already asserted $x \in A$. So we have $x \in A \wedge x \in B \implies x \in A \cap B$.

Comment: @Rob Yup, that's right.